# Array string is not being recognized as an array string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use jQueryUI's AutoComplete widget to create a search input where people can type in names and automatically find what they're looking for.

My server backend is returning the following:

```
$.get("http://localhost/academico/materias/listnames", function(data){
    $('.materiaPicker').autocomplete({
            // An example from jQueryUI documentation: 
            // source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ]

            // This is the actual returned in 'data': ["Introduccion a Marketing ","Gerencia de Preparacion y Evaluacion de Proyecto","Gerencia Estrategica"]
            source: data
        });
    });
```

Using Firebug this is the server response:

```
["Introduccion a Marketing ","Gerencia de Preparacion y Evaluacion de Proyecto","Gerencia Estrategica"]
```

Whenever I type something into the AutoComplete box, a request is fired looking something like:

```
http://localhost/academico/programaofrecidos/%5B%22Introduccion%20a%20Marketing%20%22,%22Gerencia%20de%20Preparacion%20y%20Evaluacion%20de%20Proyecto%22,%22Gerencia%20Estrategica%22%5D?term=gera
```

It's as if the data array is not being reconized as a proper array.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried adding `dataType: 'json'`?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker: Get JSON was the ticket. I'll have to read up on and it and figure out why it works though. Unless you want to write an answer for it.

Comment: Do you send the `content-type: application/json` header?

Comment: @Bergi: I don't see how that relates to the question. Would sending it cause the callback to handle `data` differently?

Comment: @Serg: Yep, jQuery attempts to infer the data type based on the MIME type of the response.

Comment: @Serg: Yes. jQuery does intelligent guessing based on the MIME type of your response, and when the server says that it's JSON then jQuery parses it and invokes the callback with a JS object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the response is interpretted as a string, and then the autocomplete use it to retrieve autoCompletion.

The URL does not begin with http://, so it is considered as a relative URL, and then, the base URL is used as a prefix.

So you have

```
   http://localhost/academico/programaofrecidos/%5B%22Introduccion%20a%20Marketing%20%22,%22Gerencia%20de%20Preparacion%20y%20Evaluacion%20de%20Proyecto%22,%22Gerencia%20Estrategica%22%5D?term=gera.
```

With

```
http://localhost/academico/programaofrecidos/
```

as the base path and

```
%5B%22Introduccion%20a%20Marketing%20%22,%22Gerencia%20de%20Preparacion%20y%20Evaluacion%20de%20Proyecto%22,%22Gerencia%20Estrategica%22%5D
```

is you 'array' (in fact a string representing an array) URL encoded.

Intelligent Guess may be not sufficient, append the **dataType** to 'json' in your call, and eventually append **JSON header** on the server side.